# Hibernate: mapping collection property with alternate join column

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-mapping

Scenario: Hibernate 3.6 with xml-based mapping, Java7, Postgresql 8.3.

I'm currently refactoring an application where I have got this scenario for the database:

```
main_table
 id integer
 other_field string 
 (id) PK


secondary_table
 other_field string
 value string
 (other_field, value) PK
```

Basically, there's a secondary table which contains an "other_field" which is matched on the main table; I need to extract all values for a certain record in main_table and map them.

In SQL I'd use a query like:

```
SELECT value FROM secondary table INNER JOIN main_table ON secondary_table.other_field == main_table.other_field where main_table.id = 1;
```

But I don't understand how to map a collection of basic types (strings) to the Main object in Java using such a query (or a similar one if the one I propose is not hibernate friendly), so that I can have a "values" property on my mapped object, which should be a Set<String>

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
@Entity
public class Primary { // Main table
  @Id
  @Column(name="EMP_ID")
  private long id;
  ...
  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(
        name="PRIMARY_SECONDARY",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PRIMARY_ID")
  )
  private Set<Secondary> phones;
  ...
}

@Embeddable
public class Secondary {  // Secondary table
  private String value;
  ...
}
```

[Full example and further details.](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection)

Comment: Wouldn't that rely on `secondary table` having a `primary_id` numeric column to join on? Or can this be a `string`, too?